# Why doesn't Jayrock (.NET JSON-RPC Framework) like my request?

Tags: web-services, json, json-rpc, jayrock

Hi quick question about Jayrock...  I have a Jayrock JSON-RPC web service that generally works fine.  However, when I try to post to my jqGrid editUrl, Jayrock throws an error.  The web service works fine in other situations.

Anyone have a clue why Jayrock doesn't like the following request?  Perhaps a way to configure Jayrock to accept this request?

**Request:**

> POST
>   /StoryManager/StoryManager.ashx/setPageItemRoles
>   HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: localhost:2064
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U;
>   Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1)
>   Gecko/20090624 Firefox/3.5 (.NET CLR
>   3.5.30729)
>
> Accept: */*
>
> Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
>
> Accept-Charset:
>   ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
>
> Keep-Alive: 300
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Content-Type:
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
>   charset=UTF-8
>
> X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
>
> Referer:
>   http://localhost:2064/StoryManager/PageItemDetail.aspx
>
> Content-Length: 183
>
> Cookie:
>   ASP.NET_SessionId=uycy1qmowzzqhiac1kg3e455
>
> Pragma: no-cache
>
> Cache-Control: no-cache
>
> title=Narrative&assignedto=dfghdfgh&assigned=2009-06-25T14%3A52%3A24.0868931-05%3A00&due=2009-08-02T14%3A52%3A24.0868931-05%3A00&completed=2009-07-17T14%3A52%3A24.0868931-05%3A00&id=3

**Response:**

> {"id":null,"error":{"name":"JSONRPCError","message":"Found
>   String where Object was
>   expected.","stackTrace":"   at
>   Jayrock.Json.JsonReader.ReadToken(JsonTokenClass
>   token) in
>   c:\Projects\Public\Jayrock\rel\rel-0.9.8316\src\Jayrock.Json\Json\JsonReader.cs:line
>   142\r\n   at
>   Jayrock.JsonRpc.JsonRpcDispatcher.ParseRequest(TextReader
>   input) in
>   c:\Projects\Public\Jayrock\rel\rel-0.9.8316\src\Jayrock\JsonRpc\JsonRpcDispatcher.cs:line
>   271\r\n   at
>   Jayrock.JsonRpc.JsonRpcDispatcher.Process(TextReader
>   input, TextWriter output) in
>   c:\Projects\Public\Jayrock\rel\rel-0.9.8316\src\Jayrock\JsonRpc\JsonRpcDispatcher.cs:line
>   127","errors":[{"name":"JsonException","message":"Found
>   String where Object was expected."}]}}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you send application/x-www-form-urlencoded request with "form-like" post data instead of application/json with correct json object.

Comment: Thanks.  I figured that out but forgot to post the answer here ;)